# Trigger Switched On/Off using Custom Metadata

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting, business-logic

I want to switch of trigger to run or not based on custom metadata.

Below is the logic I used, but getting null exception if no User record in metadata.
I don't want triger to fire when user and checkbox is ticked in custom metdata.
Else no need to run trigger.

```
    Map<string, Trigger_Configuration__mdt> tcmap =new  Map<string,Trigger_Configuration__mdt>();

    for(Trigger_Configuration__mdt tc:[SELECT Trigger_Off__c FROM Trigger_Configuration__mdt WHERE DeveloperName ='user']) {
        tcmap.put(tc.label,tc);
    } 

    if(tcmap==null || tcmap.get('user').Trigger_Off__c==false) {
        //perform operation
    }
```

Comment: This all good, just check for the map key before accessing it using `Map.containsKey(keyToConfirm)`

Comment: Why custom metadata and not custom settings?

Answer (score 1):

This all good, just check for the map key before accessing it using `Map.containsKey(keyToConfirm)`

```
if(tcmap==null || !tcmap.containsKey('user') || tcmap.get('user').Trigger_Off__c==false) {

    //perform operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good idea, and I would like to put my suggestion for you to take a look [how Salesforce Foundation has already developed this mechanism](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/eda-configuration-and-data-import/automate-tasks-with-table-driven-trigger-management-tdtm).

It is possible to extract the logic, and functionality from their [github](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/EDA/tree/main/force-app/main/tdtm) page (keeping the copyrights as is), and leverage on that.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you happen to have updated links? The ones above are moved

Comment: @TemporaryFix Updated new links, wasn't too easy to find though :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use global settings then you just simply read them in apex

```
trigger newAccounts on account (after insert) {

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert) {
        
      if(!myGlobalSetting__c.getOrgDefaults().Disable_newAccountTrigger__c) {
          abTriggerHelpers.handleNewAccounts(Trigger.new);
        }
    }

}
```